# How can I install OpenCL in Ubuntu 12.10 with a Lenovo G570 laptop?

Tags: drivers, lenovo, opencl

Is it possible, and if so, how do I install OpenCL drivers for a Lenovo G570's default graphics card?
Edit: Lenovo's website says my graphics are Intel® HD Graphics (integrated).

Comment: What, if anything, have you tried so far? Any additional info would be helpful for us to help you.

Comment: I haven't found anything so far. I just want to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have to download OpenCL for Intel, but not for the HD Graphics, as (my guess), it is not a GPU. 
So , if you want to use OpenCL, you really need to install OpenCl to use with the CPU , that is , Intel.
Take a look here
http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl-sdk
http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-opencl-sdk

p.s  My Lenovo has NVidia, then, I had installed NVidia driver and it comes with OpenCL ..

I hope it helps you.